# How to Do the Authentication in Rest Assured?

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, credentials, rest-assured

Unable to Authenticate the API using the Rest Assured?
Could somebody share 1 Example for Authentication and Authorization of API Using the Rest Assured?

Answer (score 1):

**BASIC Authentication**

```
 given().auth()
  .basic("username", "password")
  .when()
  .get("http://anyURL")
  .then()
  .assertThat()
  .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

**PREEMPTIVE Authentication**

```
 given().auth()
      .preemptive()
      .basic("username", "password")
      .when()
      .get("http://anyURL")
      .then()
      .assertThat()
      .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

**DIGEST Authentication**

```
 given().auth()
      .digest("username", "user1Pass")
      .when()
      .get("http://anyURL")
      .then()
      .assertThat()
      .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

**FORM Authentication**

```
given().auth()
  .form("user1", "user1Pass")
  .when()
  .get("http://anyURL")
  .then()
  .assertThat()
  .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

**OAuth Authentication**

```
given().auth()
  .oauth2(accessToken)
  .when()
  .get("http://anyURL")
  .then()
  .assertThat()
  .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

**AUTHORIZATION**

```
given()
       .header("Authorization", "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
       .when()
       .get("http://anyURL")
       .then()
       .assertThat()
       .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```